# Url rewriting htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have the link: domain.com/activate/
That works, in the activate page i have get form. And if i run that i get:
domain.com/activate/?code=heresomecodething

But that doesnt work.
My original url is: domain.com/index.php?p=activate&code=heresomecodething
I want that i works like this: domain.com/activate/code=heresomecodething
How can i do that??

My htaccess:

```
 RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

I hope you under stand me.

Thanks!
- Marijn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)$ /index.php?p=$1&$2 [L,NE]
```

The URI that you want to submit looks like `/activate/code=heresomecodething`, so the `([^/]+)` matches the `activate` and the `(.*)` matches the `code=heresomecodething`, both are backreferenced via the `$1` and `$2`:

```
/index.php?p=$1&$2
```

would be:

```
/index.php?p=activate&code=heresomecodething
```

This rule **ONLY** takes a URI that looks like `/activate/code=heresomecodething` and internally rewrites (behind the scenes/the browser is completely uneffected) to the URI with query strings.